# Which Component Type to add a Lightning Record Page to a Change Set

Tags: change-set, lightning-record-page

I am trying to deploy a lightning record page between sandboxes using change sets.
It deploys successfully, but the page is not correct.  I included regular page layouts, record types, all profiles, etc. to migrate page layout assignments as well, which seems to work, but I still do not see the version of the Lightning record page that I migrated.

In order to troubleshoot, I would like to query the Lightning Page Record in workbench or dev console, but I cannot find the object name of "Lightning (Opportunity) record page".

According to Salesforce documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm there is a component type "Lightning Page" but I cannot find it.  Does anyone know what object stores the Lightning record page layout metadata?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Are you using standard change sets? There should be a "lightning page" selection. If you're not using the standard change set, it's usually called "flexipage" as mentioned in the metadata and tooling api docs.

[image]
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flexipage.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm

In terms of workbench, you can query flexipages with the following

```
/services/data/v46.0/tooling/query/?q=select+id,DeveloperName+from+flexipage
```

[image]